# What are these things on/under my M.2 SSDs

Tags: laptop, ssd

So i ordered an msi gs75 from a company and i customized it from their website so they added a 500gb samsung 970 evo. When i got my laptop and removed the back panel, i saw this blue thing **on** 970 evo. I also saw this yellow thing **under** the other ssd. The yellow one is sticky.

Do these have any use at all? Are they supposed to take the heat from m.2 ssd and transfer it to the metal below? Are they supposed to keep the ssd from moving around?(not needed since it is screwed in.)

[image: Photo]

Comment: You mean the thermal pad?

Comment: @Ramhound I look at videos of m.2 SSDs on youtube and i never saw someone else use those things. Why do my laptop have them? Are you sure they are thermal pads? Why do one of them have the thermal pad under it and the other one has it on it?

Comment: Thermal pads are a somewhat new addition to the M.2 SSD world. I don't think they are a must-have for most users, but I suspect you will be seeing them down the line in factory installed M.2 drives.

Answer (score 1):

These are thermal pads for improved cooling. Current motherboards oftentimes include heatsinks as well, and there are M.2 SSDs that come with heatsinks, for example the [Western Digital Black SN750 NVME SSD](https://www.wd.com/products/internal-ssd/wd-black-sn750-nvme-ssd.html).

This particular SSD, the Samsung 970 EVO, has a power consumption of Average 5.7 W, Maximum 10.0 W per the [Samsung Website](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evo/).
So it makes sense to assure proper cooling of the device.

Comment: Which side should the heatsink be on? The yellow heatsink sticks to the ssd but blue one doesnt stick. When i opened the laptop the yellow heatsink was under the ssd and blue heatsink was above the ssd. But of course above and below is inverted when i put the back panel back on the laptop and turn it to use it.

Comment: @madcobra - You describe the correct installation